# How do we highlight the question within a question?

Tags: support

Sometimes within a question I write a precise question with a question-mark at the end, but also include within the body a bit of background.

I usually think it's clear exactly what the question is but sometimes the question is closed as "unclear what you're asking".

> Is there some formatting method that can highlight the question over and above the background info?

Comment: When appropriate I put the question (or a key conclusion in an answer) into a highlighted box. See my edit to your post. This is known as *blockquote*. Click the question mark in the edit menu to see more features available to you. There are other ways of emphasizing selected passages. Feel free to experiment and do what works for you.

Comment: Related (to some extent): [Is using blockquote for highlighting problematic?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/23015) (And perhaps some of other questions [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/23015).)